# I can't add css style to programmatically generated table cells with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table

I'm currently building a website and I need to generate a table with ajax.
I use 2 dropDropDown list and I have a jquery event on both of them. When I change the index of the dropdownlists I get data from a webservice and foreach 'lines' of data, I try to generate rows and add them to a table.

```
$("#<%=DropDownListDomaine.ClientID%>").on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'TableAutoCompletion.asmx/getDomaineSpecialites',
                data: '{"idType":"' + $('#<%=DropDownListType.ClientID%>').val() + '","idDomaine":"' + $('#<%=DropDownListDomaine.ClientID%>').val() + '"}',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#<%=TableCellDispo.ClientID%>").empty();
                    $.each(result.d, function (index, string) {
                        var array1 = string.split('|');

                        [Need help here]

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

I have in 'array1' 3 values and I need to add a single row to a table with these values.

Thats easy, but I need to have css in table cells.

So I tried many things but I cant figure it out.

```
 $("#<%=TableCellDispo.ClientID%>").append("<tr class='highlight'> <td class='taille50'>" + array1[0] + "</td><td class='taille250'>" + array1[1] + "</td><td class='taille250'> " + array1[2] + "</td> </tr> ");
```

or stuff like :

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('highlight');
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
     var cell = $('<td></td>').addClass('taille50').text(array1[i]);;
                            row.append(cell);
}

$("#<%=TableCellDispo.ClientID%>").append(row);
```

I just cant get css style in table cell.

Please help :(

(here's a screenshot with chrome console, css_code and  result) http://hpics.li/a8c5f5c)

Edit : Somehow, not clearing all rows and keeping first one 'fix' the problem. And this 'first row' is generated on init of the page with correct size. If anyone has a proper solution, I will take it.

Answer (score 0):

'Width' jquery function work. I didn't know about this one :

```
$.each(result.d, function (index, string) {
    var array1 = string.split('|');

    var i = 0; 
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('highlight');
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

         var cell, taille;
         if (i == 0)
              cell = $('<td></td>').width(50).text(array1[i]);
         else
              cell = $('<td></td>').width(250).text(array1[i]);

         row.append(cell);
    } 

    $("#<%=TableCellDispo.ClientID%>").append(row); 
});
```